# ansible: raw module to systemctl stop a nonexistent service, it returns unreachble

Tags: ansible

I run a ansible hoc command. I use raw module to systemctl stop a nonexistent service, and it return s unreachable.

```bash
bash-5.0$ ansible -i your.ini all -m raw -a "systemctl stop node_exporter.service"
172.16.4.170 | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Invalid/incorrect password: Shared connection to 172.16.4.170 closed.",
    "unreachable": true
}
bash-5.0$ ansible -i your.ini all -m raw -a "systemctl status node_exporter.service --no-pager"
172.16.4.170 | FAILED | rc=4 >>
Unit node_exporter.service could not be found.
Shared connection to 172.16.4.170 closed.
non-zero return code
```

I know I can use `service` module to get job done, I just wanna know why did this happen.
Any other command would return a correct answer, except `systemctl stop` command.
Besides, `shell` module with `systemctl stop` command also returns coreect answer.

I'm quite confused.

Comment: It not only returns `UNREACHABLE`, but additionally `Invalid/incorrect password` and `rc=4`. According [systemctl - service exit codes and status information explanation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/458655/266568), the Return Code (RC) means "_4 EXIT_NOPERMISSION The user has insufficient privileges_".

Answer (score 0):

I've got answer from ansible community, link [here](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/79337#issuecomment-1307395969).

```
systemctl returns rc=5 when the service does not exist, sshpass ALSO returns rc=5 when the password is invalid, in this case they are overlapping, there is really no way we can distinguish between both when using raw. This is done to avoid account locking.

One workaround is switching to key based auth and bypass the code that handles rc=5 when sshpass is used.
```